# Is chrome.storage.sync data cleared when an extension or app is uninstalled?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a [simple Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-simple-tasks/bngpflcpbefndiblbdjokgpmbldcoplk) that uses [chrome.storage.sync](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) to store a list of tasks.

The following command in the console would clear all sync data for the extension:

```
chrome.storage.sync.clear()
```

If my users are having trouble with syncing, can I simply instruct them to uninstall the extension and install it again to have the same effect as that command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's one of those questions where the answer is "why don't you try it?"

I have a test extension published in Chrome Web Store for `storage.sync` testing. I can confirm that uninstalling it with Chrome Sync enabled nukes the storage.